# Unable to convert .ui to .py using pyuic4 command

Tags: python, pyqt

I was using Python 2.7 with PyQt4 and converting .ui files to .py using '**pyuic4** 'command. Everything was perfect.

Few days back I installed Python 3.5 + PyQt5. I am using '**pyuic5**' command for .ui to .py conversion which is also working perfectly.

Now I created a .ui file in PyQt4. But I am unable to covert it to .py using '**pyuic4**'. I am getting the error.

[image: Image attached]

I am not getting why this is happening.

My system is having the following thing installed:

1) Python 2.7, PyQt4, Qt4

2) Python 3.5, PyQt5, Qt5

Comment: I think I may know what is causing the problem, have you added both python versions to path?   I have a feeling the `pyuic4` command is using the python 3.5 and not 2.7, hence causing a crash

Comment: Yes, I have cheked it by typing 'python' in cmd and it is showing Python 3.5 only. But how to solve it.

Comment: I think that may be it then.  Change the path so it points to 2.7 and not the 3.5 (when you type python, 2.7 should come up)

Comment: If this works I'll type up an answer with a better solution

Comment: I have set the path in environment variables for both of them but still not working. Shall I set only one i.e. Python 2.7?

Comment: If you type `python` in cmd and 3.5 comes up, then remove it completely from path.  If it does come up with 2.7, I'm out of ideas; sorry

Comment: Thanks..It worked..Now I can see Python 2.7. But .ui to .py conversion issue is still there.